# How do you find out if a subset which is a multiple/sum of functions is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V=\{f:R → R\}$, which is a vector space over the field $R$, how would you go about proving/disproving whether the subsets $\{f:R → R:f(1)f(3)=0\}$ and $\{f:R → R:f(1)+f(3)=0\}$ are subspaces or not?

Comment: Look at the definition of "subspace" -- contains $0$ and closed under some operations -- and see if they are true in these cases.

Comment: I know how to use the subspace test but I don’t understand how to apply this to a function I know nothing about?

Comment: It's not always work, but usually the sums are vector spaces and the products are not (usually the product one isn't close under the additive operation). In your example if you want to show that the first one is not a vector space you need to find functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(1)f(3)=0$ and $g(1)g(3)=0$ but the sum is not. You can take $f(x)=x-1$ and $g(x)=x-3$.

Comment: You don't need to know anything about the functions except that they satisfy the conditions.  If $f(1)f(3)=0, g(1)g(3)=0$ is it true that $(f+g)(1)\cdot(f+g)(3)=0?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first subset of $V$ is not a vector space. Indeed $ f(x): = x-1$ and $g(x):= x-3$ are both in that subset, however $f(x) +g(x)= 2(x-2)$ and thus $f+g$ does not lie in that subset. (As suggested by Yanko)

Your second subset is indeed a sub space of V. Indeed $ \phi: V \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\phi(f):= f(1) +f(3)$ is a linear map from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore its kernel is a subspace of $V$ and this is exactly the subset you are considering.

I hope this answers your question !

Comment: I suggest you replace the first line with "The first subset of $V$ is not a vector space. Indeed $f(x)=x-1$ and $g(x)=x-3$ are both in that subset, however $(f+g)(x)=2(x-2)$ which does not lie in that subset." Maybe also choose a symbol for the map from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$. It is unlikely that the OP understands what $x\mapsto f(x)$ means.

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes a lot more sense now! :)